# Get row number for selected item from list view c#

Tags: c#

How to get row number for selected item from list view in c#

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if( (listView1 row numer for selectitem) > 2 )
   {
      int indx = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
      listView1.Items[indx].Remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to get the Index? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if me select item i need to get  row number for this select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the SelectedIndexChanged event instead...  Index location is zero based, so if you have 10 items your indexes will be 0 - 9.  If you're thinking that 0 is row 1 then just add one.  Lastly, when an item is not selected the index is -1

```
private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListView1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        // Add 1 so you have 1 - 10 instead of 0 - 9
        int rowNumber = ListView1.SelectedIndex + 1;

        // Your example says you want to delete the selected index
        // so you still would want to use the selected index
        ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(ListView1.SelectedIndex);

        // After you remove the item, this method will fire again
        // but the selected index will be -1 so none of this code will
        // execute again.
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this code only supports select one row at a time.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx might be helpful.

That is, listen to the ItemSelectionChanged event instead, and use the ItemIndex property on the event data.

E.g. the Microsoft example shows

```
private void ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(
    Object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) {

    var i = e.ItemIndex; // got the latest selection
}
```

Comment: thanks you but if you select any item in list view need gate row number for this item select

Comment: Tried to update the answer to reflect what I think you're asking. I'm sorry to say the language barrier is high - I don't fully understand your English and am guessing at your intent.